# How to get lock screen option in Lubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen, lxde

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with many DE. Lubuntu is one of them. I don't have any option to lock screen in Lubuntu while I do in Unity and other DE.

Is there any program / application that I can install in order to lock screen in Lubuntu?

Comment: Have you installed lubuntu-desktop or only lxde?

Comment: actually both but I've that application in my list of apps because I've got more environments installed as gnome shell , unity and kde recently .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just use the keybindings I've always used on ubuntu. Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Should work

Comment: Cool man +1  , i have tried and Its worked . But are sure about this , that it will work in Lubuntu too ?

Comment: this is a keybinding. he asked for "program/application". It gives him a good start on finding the answer he is seeking, but doesnt tell him where to look though (openbox configuration file).

Answer (score 3):

There is an article at the [here](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=31300) at the LXDE forums. It gives instructions on creating a **.desktop** file to lock the screen, and adding it to the top panel.

Comment: hey i have tried that & did as it said but i am not getting screen lock option while with application launcher option .

Answer (score 3):

The `lxlock` program provides screen locking functionality in LXDE.

It is [part of lxsession](https://github.com/eshizhan/lxsession/blob/master/lxlock). The [lxsession [image: Install lxsession]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lxsession) package provides it.

Try running `lxlock` from the Run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or **LXDE Menu** > **Run**) or the LXTerminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

If `lxlock` locks the screen, you can work around the problem  by running it that way or by creating a launcher for it on the menu, panel, or desktop.

If `lxlock` runs but does not lock the screen, that's probably [a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

If `lxlock` is not present on your system, run this to install (or, if it's installed but damaged, to reinstall) the `lxsession` package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install lxsession
```

After installing that, `lxlock` should work, but if it runs and fails, try logging off and back on to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `lubuntu-default-settings` package. Open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-default-settings
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it. The easiest being:

LXDE Menu - Other - Lock Screen (XScreensaver).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

open `.config` file and right click on `lxde-rc.xml` open with any editor 
and find desktop paste the below  script  on keyboard below

```
<keybind key="W-L">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

save the file 
exit
reboot the system 
it will be work properly.